# Flutter Mobx - Passing store state between pages in PageView

Tags: flutter, state, mobx, pageviews

How can i pass or preserve the state of my store between pages using PageView?

By example, I'm trying to upload an image at the first page to edit, and pass to a second page where i want to show the image with a form. Im using MVC, and the image is set via controller (store), but it's not working. I've been made some tests and sometimes, at debugging runtime, the image is shown at the second page. But, sometimes even debugging it isn't shown and its value is null. 
I tried with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin also, but the behavior is the same.

Someone can tell me what i'm doing wrong or what i'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

I think using singleton can solve your problem, actually I think I had this problem in two apps I made.

I used [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) plugin, this package creates singletons easily for you and it's simple to retrieve anywhere in the app without using context.

First, register your MobX as Singleton, I do it on main:

```
getIt.I.registerSingleton<YourStore>(YourStore());
```

Retrieve the same instance of your Store, if you have observables in the first page and call an action on the second page, it will trigger the observables in the first page or wherever you used any observable from this instance of Store.

```
GetIt.I<YourStore>().changeImageFromFirstPage();
```

You can call GetIt.I().youraction() anywhere in your app, it will trigger the observables you created on this Store.

Comment: In fact the problem occurs from second to third page. When i use from first to second i can retrieve the variable value. Im using a framework that already uses get_it for DI. As a workaround now im accessing the first page outside the pageview. But soon ill need to use three or more pages inside the pageview and try to use the get.I itself to see if it works. Tnks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
final list = Provider.of<TodoList>(context);
```

in the MobX document, there is a provider that can be used as the above code.
I use GetIt too, it is really awesome.

there is a sample for this in the following URL for the MobX:
https://mobx.netlify.app/examples/todos